# Print sorted dict (tuple) with new line for each entry

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, printing

I have this dict sorted by frequency with `import sys from operator import itemgetter`:

```
dictionarydata =  {('to', 4648), ('a', 4667), ('and', 6407), ('of', 6703)}
```

When I `print(dictionarydata)` I want the output like:

```
to : 4648
a : 4667
and : 6407
of : 6703
```

All I have tried doesn't work. For exymple regular expressions doesn't seem to work with tuple; e.g.

```
import re 
with open(dictionarydata) as f: 
for line in f: 
for word in re.findall(r'\w+', line): 
print(word)
```

Comment: _"All I have tried doesn't work"_. Show us at least one thing you tried, and we'll start from there.

Comment: if `x` is your list of tuples, try this: `print("\n".join(["{} : {}".format(*l) for l in x]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have what appears to be your `set` of tuples:

```
x = {('to', 4648), ('a', 4667), ('and', 6407), ('of', 6703)}
```

format it using `\n` to join the lines, and `str.format` to create the lines you want:

```
print("\n".join(["{} : {}".format(*l) for l in x]))
```

result:

```
to : 4648
a : 4667
and : 6407
of : 6703
```

note that because your input is a `set`, order isn't guaranteed. It would be if it was a `list` or a `tuple`.

Answer (score 0):

```
items = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
for (key, value) in items:
    print(key, ":", value)
```

This will give the output:

```
a : 1
b : 2
c : 3
```

This is also be the same as doing:

```
for x in items:
    print(x[0], ":", x[1])
```

for example.